# How to set and access a custom pre-processor variable?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, preprocessor-directive

I'm working on making a Fortran application run on both Windows and Linux. Up till now, it's been Windows only. For now, the Linux version is entirely terminal-based while the Windows version has a GUI. We will have a GUI for the Linux version eventually.

To handle differences between Windows and Linux, I've been using pre-processor directives like

```
!DEC$ IF DEFINED(_WIN32)
...
!DEC$ ELSEIF DEFINED(__linux)
...
!DEC$ ENDIF
```

This works well for what I need right now, since I know the Windows version always has a GUI and the Linux version never has a GUI. However, I'd like to split that out so that eventually I can have both GUI and GUI-less builds on both OSs.

Is there a way I can set up my own pre-processor variable so that I can have statements like

```
!DEC$ IF DEFINED(GUI)
...
!DEC$ ELSE
...
!DEC$ ENDIF
```

So basically, how would I tell the pre-processor I want a variable called `GUI` and how would I set its value? I know I'm probably not using the proper terminology as I'm not terribly familiar with this kind of programming. Feel free to correct my syntax.

Comment: What preprocessor is this?

Comment: I'm using Intel Fortran

Comment: Consider using the fpp preprocessor instead (available in Intel Fortran) The code wikl be more portable.

Comment: How do I change which preprocessor I'm using? And why would the preprocessor change the portability of the code?

Comment: The preprocessor supplied by Intel Fortran is fine. If you are on Linux, then it gets invoked automatically if your source file has a .F90 or .F file type with a capital F.

Comment: I see. I had a look at my CMakeLists and realized I am invoking the fpp preprocessor, so I should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done with a command line option for the build variant. Most compilers use -D (or /D) for this, for example, `-DGUI`, which defines a symbol `GUI` you can test for (the value will be 1 unless you give a different one.) Check your compiler's documentation to see what the option is.

Comment: So I can use ```IF DEFINED``` to check if ```GUI``` has been defined. How do I check the value of it?

Comment: `#if (GUI == 1) 
  ...`
See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2024-0/fpp-preprocessor-directives.html